# __str__(self) that returns a reasonable string representation of an album

Tags: class, python-3.x

I've got two classes here. On my class album my **str** function is not working as I'm only able to return one of the album details. 
Test:

```
t1 = Track('Bicyclops', 'Bela Fleck', 260)
t3 = Track('Watch What Happens', 'Frank Sinatra', 200)
album1 = Album('My Way', 'Frank Sinatra', '1969', [t1, t3])
print(album1)
```

What it returns `My Way by Frank Sinatra (1969)`

But I want it to return 

`My Way by Frank Sinatra (1969)
Track: Bicyclops by Bela Fleck (260)
Track: Watch What Happens by Frank Sinatra (200)`

I know I need to create a seperate function and call it in the **str** but I'm not sure how to approach it. I've created the extra function track_list but not 100% sure. This is really long question but was the only way i could explain it the best way.

```
class Track: 

def __init__(self, title, artist,duration): 
    self.artist = artist 
    self.title = title 
    self.duration = duration 

def __repr__(self): 
    return 'Track(' + str(self.artist) + ", " +  str(self.title) + ", " + str(self.duration) + ')'

def __str__(self): 
    return "Track: " + str(self.title) + " by " + str(self.artist) + " (" + str(self.duration) + ")" 

def get_artist(self):
    return self.artist 

def get_title(self): 
    return self.title 

def get_duration(self): 
    return self.duration
```

class Album:

```
def __init__(self, title, artist, year, list_of_tracks): 
    self.artist = artist 
    self.title = title 
    self.year = year
    self.list_of_tracks = list_of_tracks 

def __repr__(self): 
    return 'Album(' + str(self.artist) + ", " + str(self.title) + ", " + str(self.year) + ')'

def track_list(self,artist,title,duration): 
    track1 =  "Track: " + str(self.title) + " by " + str(self.artist) + " (" + str(self.duration) + ")" 
    track2 =  "Track: " + str(self.title) + " by " + str(self.artist) + " (" + str(self.duration) + ")" 
    return track1, track2 

def __str__(self): 
    return str(self.title) + " by " + str(self.artist) + " (" + str(self.year) + ")"
```

Comment: you need to ensure that your `__str__` method on the album actually calls `__str__` on each track in `list_of_tracks` - also your `__str__` must return a string - your current code doesn't return anything.

Comment: at the moment its returning just one thing which is  My Way by Frank Sinatra (1969)

Comment: thats the part I'm confused with I'm not sure how to call each track from the track_list function which i created. Hoping that the track_list function is correct

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
class Album:
   ..............
   def __str__(self):  
    return str(self.title) + " by " + str(self.artist) + " (" + str(self.year) + ")"+str(self.list_of_tracks)
```

if you want in separate lines,

Method 1:

```
class Album:
   ..............
 def __str__(self):  
    tempStr=''
    for item in self.list_of_tracks: 
        tempStr += '\n'+str(item);
    return str(self.title) + " by " + str(self.artist) + " (" + str(self.year) + ")"+tempStr
```

Comment: its returning this <bound method Album.track_list of Album(Frank Sinatra, My Way, 1969)>

Comment: Because the code you sent seems right, but I think something might be wrong with my def track_list function under my Album class

Comment: why you invoking "track_list"? __str__ will be automatically called when you try to print the object.

Comment: because returning list_of_tracks won't do anything ?

Comment: you have to return tracks_list

Comment: the logic inside "track_list" looks same as __start__ method of class Track , def __str__(self): 
    return "Track: " + str(self.title) + " by " + str(self.artist) + " (" + str(self.duration) + ")"

Comment: why you using track_list method ?

Comment: okay true, how come I'm getting this <bound method Album.track_list of Album(Frank Sinatra, My Way, 1969)> when i run it

Comment: I created a function called track_list which needs to be called in the str in order to call the other things from the other class

Comment: It's working in my environment. I tested your code locally. Can u share the out put that you are getting.

Comment: can you be little specific about this "which needs to be called in the str in order to call the other things from the other class"

Comment: so its printing out this : My Way by Frank Sinatra (1969)
Track: Bicyclops by Bela Fleck (260)
Track: Watch What Happens by Frank Sinatra (200)

Comment: its working now but its printing differently :                                                 [Track(Bela Fleck, Bicyclops, 260), Track(Frank Sinatra, Watch What Happens, 200)]

Comment: thats how its coming out, its not coming as "newlines" and its got the "[" bracket next to Track

Comment: I removed "tracks_list" function and updated __str__ to the below  and it's worked for me ,
   
   def __str__(self): 
  samplestr=''  
  for item in self.list_of_tracks:
   samplestr += '\n' + str(item)
  return str(self.title) + " by " + str(self.artist) + " (" + str(self.year) + ")"+samplestr